# Take difference between two dates from Monday to Sunday

Tags: javascript

I have a simple Javascript function that calculates the weeks between two dates, every seven days equals one week:

```
function getWeeksDiff(startDate, endDate) {
  const msInWeek = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7;

  return Math.round(Math.abs(endDate - startDate) / msInWeek);
}
```

It works correctly, but now I want to change the logic. I want to take a week from every Monday to Saturday regardless of the day it is on and that is not strictly related to 7 days

For example: Today is November 23, so 24,25,26 and 27 must count 1 week, and from Monday 28 to Sunday 4 it must count two weeks, so my logic is as follows:

```
const week = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7;
const day = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;

  function weeksBetween(startDate, endDate) {
             return Math.ceil((weekStart(endDate) - weekStart(startDate)) / week) + 1;
         }

 function weekStart(dt) {
     const weekday = dt.getDay();
     return new Date(dt.getTime() - Math.abs(0 - weekday) * day);
 }
```

But for some reason, every Sunday it calculates one more week, for example, Sunday the 27th already shows me two weeks instead of one:

```js
const week = 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
const day = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;

function weekStart(dt) {
    const weekday = dt.getDay();
    return new Date(dt.getTime() - Math.abs(0 - weekday) * day);
}

function weeksBetween(d1, d2) {
    return Math.ceil((weekStart(d2) - weekStart(d1)) / week)+1;
}

console.log(weeksBetween(new Date("11/23/2022"), new Date("11/27/2022")));
```

Comment: I can understand your logic for `November 23, so 24,25,26 and 27` but how about extending from Monday 28 to Thursday 1? Do you count it as a week as well?

Comment: Yes, every monday should sum a week, so monday 21 to sunday 27 should return 2 , from monday 28 should count 3, etc @NickVu

Comment: The problem is the formula is not correct (to determine partial weeks).

Comment: I'm confused, you said `November 23, so 24,25,26 and 27 must count 1 week`, but now you want to have `monday 21 to sunday 27 should return 2`, it should be 1 instead, right? @Jesus

Comment: Sorry you're right; I will be more explicit from each Monday; I don't care if the user picks Tuesday, Wednesday, etc. (day of the week). It should count as one week, then i.e. if start date is a Tuesday and the end date is in the same week it should be one week, but if the end date it's from Monday or whatever other day of next week, it should count 2, and the same for week three etc. @NickVu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function countWeeks(startDate, endDate) {
    // Calculate the next Sunday from the startDate 
    // Change the 0 if you need a different day to start the week
    const firstWeek = startDate.getDate() + (7 + 0 - startDate.getDay()) % 7;
    const newStartDate = new Date(startDate.setDate(firstWeek));

    // Remove that partial week and calculate how many partial weeks remaining
    return Math.ceil((endDate-newStartDate)/1000/60/60/24/7) + 1;

}

const date1 = new Date('11/20/2022');
const date2 = new Date('11/27/2022');
console.log(countWeeks(date1, date2)); // 2

const date3 = new Date('11/1/2022');
const date4 = new Date('11/29/2022');
console.log(countWeeks(date3, date4)); // 5
```

Credit where credit is due: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/33527/find-next-occurring-friday-or-any-dayofweek

Comment: I tested and if I use the end date tomorrow should count as 2 weeks, because today is 1 week, and all next week should be 2 weeks, from Monday 5 to Sunday 11 should be 3 weeks etc.

Comment: I understood your question to be Sunday to Monday is 1 week. 
I'd have to rewrite the `first` variable formula to calculate weeks Monday to Sunday.

Comment: That should do it for you -- remade for Sundays. My mistake for reading the question poorly!

Answer (score 0):

```js
function weeksBetween(startDate, endDate) {
  const dayTimestamp = 24 * 3600 * 1000
  //count how many days between 2 dates
  const days = 1 + Math.round((endDate - startDate) / dayTimestamp);

  //get the day difference from the current date with Monday
  const dayDiff = (startDate.getDay() + 6) % 7
  
  //the default count is always 1, and calculate how many full weeks go from the start date to the end date
  //a full week will be 7 days
  return 1 + Math.floor((days + dayDiff) / 7);
}
console.log("11/22/2022 - 11/24/2022:",weeksBetween(new Date("11/22/2022"), new Date("11/24/2022")));

console.log("11/21/2022 - 11/28/2022:",weeksBetween(new Date("11/21/2022"), new Date("11/28/2022")));

console.log("11/21/2022 - 11/29/2022:",weeksBetween(new Date("11/21/2022"), new Date("11/29/2022")));

console.log("11/23/2022 - 12/04/2022:",weeksBetween(new Date("11/23/2022"), new Date("12/04/2022")));
```